# Akka-Http how to deal with special characters in the URL (like %)

Tags: scala, akka, url-encoding, akka-http

In my akka http app I receive a lot of errors like this one:

```
Illegal request-target: Invalid input 'v', expected HEXDIG (line 1, column 72)
```

It happens when I simply add a '%' character to the URL. In this case akka exoects a hex value.

Is it possible to somehow 'clean up' or encode/ignore such characters?

Comment: Why not respect the URL specification?

Comment: @ViktorKlang sure, you are right. But what if user makes a call to an invalid URL like in my question? In that case the app simply response with an 400 error w/o any HTML rendered...

Comment: That is exactly what it should respond with? 400 == Bad Request, which is exactly what it is?

Answer (score 0):

**For users of an API who got this error message and don't know how to solve it:**

I had the same problem, with a URL that queries something from a third party database, one part of the URL was simply not correct and that caused this error message.

I think this error message is misleading since it sounds like you should encode the URL differently which is not the case at all, just check if the structure of the URL is correct.